# What film had a similar plot to "In Time"?

Tags: story-identification, short-film

I've seen [this movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_Time) recently but it remind me of an excellent short from the 80's.  I'm convinced that In Time stole the idea from that short because it is identical:

- It was a dystopian future were people buy and sell stuff with the Life Expectancy (and they were using credit cards for the exchange).
- I remember you were able to see a teenage girl that "burned" herself buying drugs with her time (in a bar or something like that?), right
- I also remember that our hero tried to get a little more time for his mother...

Comment: You can accept an answer at any time by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: Hmm... I didn't think my gold-badge powers happened when mine was the only (remaining) answer.

Answer (score 1):

This may be *[The Price of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Price_of_Life_(1987_film))* as per [Time as money movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/177978/time-as-money-movie/177980#177980)

> The basic premise of the film is that a time account is physically linked to every infant at birth, with death automatic when the balance drops to zero. An elite upper-class is portrayed as living hundreds of years or more. The protagonist is given a certain amount of time as an infant, and as a young boy adds days and years to his time account by buying valuables from people and selling them to visiting tourists from the rich enclave. After his sister dies after gambling away her time, the protagonist (now a young man) sets out on a journey to the enclave of "the Old Ones" in order to save the life of his mother, who is (literally) running out of time. He gets there and meets a beautiful older woman who co-opts him into the immortal lifestyle.

The full movie can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oRurZ7TlACc), on Youtube.

Comment: If this is accepted, it's a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/177978/time-as-money-movie?noredirect=1&lq=1, which was accepted in the comments (and has another answer duped to it).

Comment: Oh my goodness! It is exactly that! I totally remember the car scene from childhood. yes! you mr are a genius. Thank you! I will rewatch and enjoy now thank you again

Comment: @user125137: As per the comment to your question, you can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: And please don't be dissuaded by us marking your question as a duplicate. It's book-keeping, for the most part, to tie different questions with the same answer together. Your question was a good one, good enough for me to find where someone else had answered it.